# App crashing due to two differnet Async Tasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-bitmap

So I have been working on this code for a while now trying to implement Google Visions into my prior app that displays an image from pixabay then tells me the tags of the photo.I had both the google vision app and pixabay app work just fine on their own. In this new version it should give me tags and the labels found by Google Visions but, whenever I activate the UP command on the sensors it crashes.

Here is my code:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.Vision;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.VisionRequest;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.VisionRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.BatchAnnotateImagesRequest;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.Feature;
import com.google.api.services.vision.v1.model.Image;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough.R.id.tvLabels;
import static edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough.R.id.tvTags;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    public static final String PIXABAY = "Pixabay";
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static PixabayQueryResult result;
    private String tags;
    long numberOfHits;
    long selected;

    float[] gravity = new float[3];
    float[] accel = new float[3];
    private static final float ALPHA = 0.80f; // weighing factor used by the low pass filter
    private static final String TAG = "OMNI";
    private static final float VERTICAL_TOL = 0.3f;
    private SensorManager manager;
    private long lastUpdate;
    private MediaPlayer popPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer backgroundPlayer;
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private TextView[] tvGravity;
    private TextView[] tvAcceleration;

    private boolean isDown = false;
    private boolean isUp = false;

    private static final String CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCt35MZjvD_3ynTbYmeUuBFyMbYrjXUmzs";
    private static final String ANDROID_CERT_HEADER = "X-Android-Cert";
    private static final String ANDROID_PACKAGE_HEADER = "X-Android-Package";

    private static final String TAGgoogle = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private TextView pixtags;
    private TextView googlelab;

    private String urlString;

    private Bitmap bitmapT;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        pixtags= (TextView) findViewById(tvTags);

        googlelab= (TextView) findViewById(tvLabels);

       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PixabayFetchTask task = new PixabayFetchTask();
                String service = "https://pixabay.com/api/";
                String key = "5535853-23bc4a5e307cd5d1a5e16ebcc";
                String query_params = "&editor_choice=true&safesearch=true&image_type=photo";
                String urlString = service + "?key=" + key + query_params;
                task.execute(urlString);


            }
        });*/

    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                int result1=0;
                if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    result1 = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }
                if( result1 == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result1== TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Inizalization Failed");
                }
            }
        });

        //////////////////////////
        manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        backgroundPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mistsoftime4tmono);

        //////////////////////////
      //callCloudVision("https://pixabay.com/get/eb36b90f2df1053ed95c4518b7494395e67fe7d604b0154892f2c67da7eabc_640.jpg");
    }

    ///////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        manager.registerListener(this, manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        backgroundPlayer.start();

    }

    //////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        manager.unregisterListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static long getRandomLong(long minimum, long maximum)
    {
        return (long) (Math.random()* (maximum- minimum))+ minimum;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        gravity[0] = lowPass(event.values[0], gravity[0]);
        gravity[1] = lowPass(event.values[1], gravity[1]);
        gravity[2] = lowPass(event.values[2], gravity[2]);

        accel[0] = highPass(event.values[0], accel[0]);
        accel[1] = highPass(event.values[1], accel[1]);
        accel[2] = highPass(event.values[2], accel[2]);



        long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (actualTime - lastUpdate > 100) {
            if (inRange(gravity[2], -9.81f, VERTICAL_TOL)) {

                Log.i(TAG, "Down");

                if (!isDown) {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(500);
                    PixabayFetchTask task = new PixabayFetchTask();
                    String service = "https://pixabay.com/api/";
                    String key = "5535853-23bc4a5e307cd5d1a5e16ebcc";
                    String query_params = "&editor_choice=true&safesearch=true&image_type=photo";
                    urlString = service + "?key=" + key + query_params;
                    task.execute(urlString);
                    backgroundPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                    tts.speak("The device is pointing down", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    backgroundPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    isDown = true;
                    isUp = false;

                }

            } else if (inRange(gravity[2], 9.81f, VERTICAL_TOL)) {
                if (!isUp) {
                    try {
                        callCloudVision(urlString);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    backgroundPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Up");
                    tags= (String) result.getTags((int)selected);
                    pixtags.setText("Tags: "+tags, null);
                 /*   Snackbar.make(imageView, tags, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
                    tts.speak(tags.toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);


                    //tts.speak("up", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    backgroundPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    isUp = true;
                    isDown = false;
                }

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "In between");
                //isDown = false;  // Rubbish!
                //isUp = false;
            }
            lastUpdate = actualTime;
        }

    }

    private boolean inRange(float value, float target,  float tol) {
        return value >= target-tol && value <= target+tol;
    }

    // de-emphasize transient forces
    private float lowPass(float current, float gravity) {
        return current * (1-ALPHA) + gravity * ALPHA; // ALPHA indicates the influence of past observations
    }

    // de-emphasize constant forces
    private float highPass(float current, float gravity) {
        return current - gravity;
    }




    class PixabayFetchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, PixabayQueryResult> {

        /**
         * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
         * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
         * by the caller of this task.
         * <p>
         * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
         * on the UI thread.
         *
         * @param params The parameters of the task.
         * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
         * @see #onPreExecute()
         * @see #onPostExecute
         * @see #publishProgress
         */
        @Override
        protected PixabayQueryResult doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.v(PIXABAY,"String[0] =" + params[0]);

            if(result==null || result.isExpired()) {


                try {
                    String line;
                    URL u = new URL(params[0]);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) json.append(line);
                    result = new PixabayQueryResult(json.toString());

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }



        /**
         * <p>Runs on the UI thread after {@link #doInBackground}. The
         * specified result is the value returned by {@link #doInBackground}.</p>
         * <p>
         * <p>This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.</p>
         *
         * @param bitmap The result of the operation computed by {@link #doInBackground}.
         * @see #onPreExecute
         * @see #doInBackground
         * @see #onCancelled(Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PixabayQueryResult result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
           numberOfHits= result.size();
             selected = getRandomLong(0, numberOfHits);
             Bitmap bitmap= result.getBitmap((int)selected);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           /* try {
                callCloudVision(urlString);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

        }
    }

    private void callCloudVision(final String loc) throws IOException {
        // Switch text to loading
        googlelab.setText(R.string.loading_message);

        // Do the real work in an async task, because we need to use the network anyway
        new AsyncTask<Object, Bitmap, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
                    JsonFactory jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

                    VisionRequestInitializer requestInitializer =
                            new VisionRequestInitializer(CLOUD_VISION_API_KEY) {
                                /**
                                 * We override this so we can inject important identifying fields into the HTTP
                                 * headers. This enables use of a restricted cloud platform API key.
                                 */
                                @Override
                                protected void initializeVisionRequest(VisionRequest<?> visionRequest)
                                        throws IOException {
                                    super.initializeVisionRequest(visionRequest);

                                    String packageName = getPackageName();
                                    visionRequest.getRequestHeaders().set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_HEADER, packageName);

                                    String sig = PackageManagerUtils.getSignature(getPackageManager(), packageName);

                                    visionRequest.getRequestHeaders().set(ANDROID_CERT_HEADER, sig);
                                }
                            };

                    Vision.Builder builder = new Vision.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
                    builder.setVisionRequestInitializer(requestInitializer);

                    Vision vision = builder.build();

                    BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchAnnotateImagesRequest =
                            new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
                    batchAnnotateImagesRequest.setRequests(new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>() {{
                        AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();

                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            InputStream stream = new URL(loc).openStream();
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                            publishProgress(bitmap);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Add the image
                        Image base64EncodedImage = new Image();
                        // Convert the bitmap to a JPEG
                        // Just in case it's a format that Android understands but Cloud Vision

                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);

                        byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();


                        // Base64 encode the JPEG
                        base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
                        annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage);

                        // add the features we want
                        annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(new ArrayList<Feature>() {{
                            Feature labelDetection = new Feature();
                            labelDetection.setType("LABEL_DETECTION");
                            labelDetection.setMaxResults(10);
                            add(labelDetection);
                        }});

                        // Add the list of one thing to the request
                        add(annotateImageRequest);
                    }});

                    Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
                            vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);
                    // Due to a bug: requests to Vision API containing large images fail when GZipped.
                    annotateRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    Log.d(TAGgoogle, "created Cloud Vision request object, sending request");

                    BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
                    return convertResponseToString(response);

                } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                    Log.d(TAGgoogle, "failed to make API request because " + e.getContent());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAGgoogle, "failed to make API request because of other IOException " +
                            e.getMessage());
                }
                return "Cloud Vision API request failed. Check logs for details.";
            }

            /**
             * Runs on the UI thread after {@link #publishProgress} is invoked.
             * The specified values are the values passed to {@link #publishProgress}.
             *
             * @param bitmaps The values indicating progress.
             * @see #publishProgress
             * @see #doInBackground
             */
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(bitmaps);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[0]);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                googlelab.setText(result);

            }
        }.execute();
    }
    private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {
        String message = "Labels:\n\n";

        List<EntityAnnotation> labels = response.getResponses().get(0).getLabelAnnotations();
        if (labels != null) {
            for (EntityAnnotation label : labels) {
                message += String.format(Locale.US, "%.3f: %s", label.getScore(), label.getDescription());
                message += "\n";
            }
        } else {
            message += "nothing";
        }

        return message;
    }


}
```

Here is the it gives me error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
Process: edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough, PID: 21223    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()  
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
           at edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough.MainActivity$2$2.<init>(MainActivity.java:419)
    at edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:400)
              at edu.ggc.lutz.recipe.pixabaysamplerwalkthrough.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:366) 
             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

There is another error that says something about the text to speech but I think that is the result of this error.

I believe it has something to do with running two different Async tasks at the same time overloading it or that fact a null value it getting passed in causing the error.

Comment: You need to `bitmap.compress` within the  try catch. The Bitmap is otherwise possibly null

Comment: ... b/c **`InputStream stream`** is out of scope and could possibly be garbage collected.

Comment: The bitmap.compress is already in a try. Most of the callCloudVision is in a try catch are you talking about the try catch above it because I tried that and still got the error but you are right the error does seems to target the compress statement.